# what made this make test fail?

Tags: nodeos, installation

I installed eos from source on Ubuntu 18.04. The I ran

```
make test
```

I do not have nodeos actually running at the time of testing.

And I had the following errors -

> 39/41 Test #39: validate_dirty_db_test ...............***Failed
>   0.63 sec
>         Start 40: nodeos_sanity_lr_test 40/41 Test #40: nodeos_sanity_lr_test ................***Failed    0.63 sec
>         Start 41: nodeos_voting_lr_test 41/41 Test #41: nodeos_voting_lr_test ................***Failed    0.64 sec
>
> 73% tests passed, 11 tests failed out of 41
>
> Label Time Summary: long_running_tests    =   1.27 sec*proc (2 tests)
>
> Total Test time (real) = 705.61 sec

```
The following tests FAILED: Cannot create directory
/home/trevor/eos/build/Testing/Temporary Cannot create log file:
LastTestsFailed.log      30 - plugin_test (Failed)   31 -
nodeos_sanity_test (Failed)      32 - nodeos_run_test (Failed)   34 -
nodeos_run_test-mongodb (Failed)     35 - distributed-transactions-test
(Failed)     36 - restart-scenarios-test-resync (Failed)     37 -
restart-scenarios-test-hard_replay (Failed)      38 -
restart-scenarios-test-none (Failed)     39 - validate_dirty_db_test
(Failed)     40 - nodeos_sanity_lr_test (Failed)     41 -
nodeos_voting_lr_test (Failed) Errors while running CTest
Makefile:119: recipe for target 'test' failed make: *** [test] Error 8
```

What could be the cause. I have started mongod.

Comment: I've seen a lot of these errors. I would just not worry about it unless you're getting some weird errors.  I don't make test my install anymore.

Comment: how exactly did you install EOS? did you do it as such?
git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git; cd eos; 
(first time you run the next command it'll ask you to run some command, i forget what, to update your copy of the repo fully.)
sudo ./eosio_build.sh; cd build; make test;

Answer (score 1):

I had problems getting EOS to work properly on Ubuntu 18.04. I would recommend downgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 for now if you want to work with something more stable.

However, just to be sure:
Did you do the following commands in the following order?

```
cd /path/to/eos
./eosio_build.sh
~/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod -f ~/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf &
cd build
sudo make install
sudo make test
```

It seems a lot of people forget to do the `sudo make install` command.